# Getting Windows 7's Explorer to display search box without enabling Windows search

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, search

I want to get the search box back in Windows 7 *without* having to enable the Windows Search service. Is there a registry key to make it behave like in Vista, so I can just do searches on the fly without having some pesky indexing service running in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get the search box back in
>   Win7 without having to enable the
>   Windows Search service.

this is not possible. Windows Search is required for the Search box to function.

however, you can **enable** Windows Search and **disable** indexing separately. but searches will be signifacantly slower.

Alternatively, you may want to have a look at Voidtool's **[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)**, taking Windows desktop search to a whole new level, unrivaled in speed and capability.

*Everything is freeware, a portable version is available.*

Comment: "Everything" is hands down the best of the best.

Comment: Thanks, I enabled windows search in the 'programs' control panel thingie and then I disabled the indexing service (labelled 'Windows search' in the services). It now behaves the way I want (i.e. no indexing, but I do have a search box in windows explorer and can do non-indexed searches on properties and file content).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply disable the indexing service?

Then, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and go to `View > Folder Options` and click the `Search` Tab.

Choose the second option (and anything else you want).

[image]

Comment: +1. Yep, I ended up installing windows search and then disabling the indexing service.

Answer (score 1):

There are two pretty simple ways of disabling Windows from Indexing;

- Navigate to - Start > Search 'Indexing Options' and Open > Click ' Modify' > Click 'Show All Locations'
  Now de-select anything that you dont want Windows to index. De-selecting everything effectively turns off indexing as Windows has nothing to Index.

[image]

- The other way to do this is by disabling Indexing on a drive basis. Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, right-click on the drive you want to disable and select 'Propterties'. Un-tick the box as shown below. This will disable the selected drive from being indexed.

[image]

As far as I know, both of these methods should still let you be able to search in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Thanks. +1. (I wish there was a way to mark more than one question on this site as the correct answer.)